# Python SQLAlchemy+Threading failing silently

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a server to sample a streaming price feed and update a postgres DB using SQLAlchemy. I am using threaded instances of a mapped class, which seems to work but is not stable.

There are no issues with 1 or 2 instances of the Stream class, but with say 10, the thread fails randomly and silently. Each time before it fails, SQLAlchemy gives an error message, so it seems this is what is killing the thread. There is nothing wrong with the stream, it is always stable.

Have I missed something with the SQLAlchemy setup? Is there a better way of feeding multiple realtime subscriptions into SQL?

The code:

```
import time
import json
from threading import Thread, Lock
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# Setup SQLAlchemy
engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://localhost:5432/Project', echo=False)
metadata = db.MetaData(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()

#DB classes
#static data table
class StockMaster(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stock_master'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ticker = db.Column(db.String)
    stock_name = db.Column(db.String)

    @classmethod
    def find_by_ticker(cls,ticker):
        return session.query(StockMaster).filter(StockMaster.ticker==ticker).first()

#live data table
class StockLive(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stock_live'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    quote = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    ticker_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stock_master.id'))

    ticker = relationship("StockMaster", foreign_keys=[ticker_id])

    def __init__(self, quote, ticker_id, timestamp):
        self.quote=quote
        self.ticker_id=ticker_id
        self.timestamp=timestamp

    def save_to_db(self):
        session.add(self)
        session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def find_by_ticker_id(cls,ticker_id):
        return session.query(StockLive).filter(StockLive.ticker_id==ticker_id).first()

    @classmethod
    def find_by_ticker(cls,ticker):
        ticker_id = StockMaster.find_by_ticker(ticker).id
        return session.query(StockLive).filter(StockLive.ticker_id==ticker_id).first()


class Stream(Thread):
    def __init__(self,ticker):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ticker=ticker
        self.quote=1
        self.data_set = StockLive.find_by_ticker(self.ticker)
        self.count=0

    def run(self):
        con.subscribe(self.ticker)
        current_mid=1
        while True:
            new_data = json.loads(con.get_price(self.ticker).to_json())
            new_mid = new_data['Mid']

            if new_mid == current_mid:
                pass
            else:
                current_mid = new_mid
                self.data_set.quote = current_mid
                self.data_set.timestamp = time.time()
                try:
                    self.data_set.save_to_db()
                    self.count+=1
                except:
                    self.data_set = StockLive.find_by_ticker(self.ticker)
                    print('error saving to db for '+self.ticker)
            time.sleep(.1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads={}
    for ticker in tickerlist:
        try:
            threads[ticker]=Stream(ticker)
            threads[ticker].setName('Thread ' + ticker)
            threads[ticker].start()
        except:
            print('Error setting up '+ticker)

    while True:
        for ticker in tickerlist:
            if threads[ticker].isAlive()==False:
                threads[ticker]=Stream(ticker)
```

SQLAlchemy error message:

> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2323:
>   SAWarning: Usage of the 'Session.add()' operation is not currently
>   supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may
>   not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or
>   connection-level operations instead.   % method)
>   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py:2425:
>   SAWarning: Attribute history events accumulated on 1 previously clean
>   instances within inner-flush event handlers have been reset, and will
>   not result in database updates. Consider using set_committed_value()
>   within inner-flush event handlers to avoid this warning.   % len_)
>   Exception in thread Thread MSFT: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2436, in _flush
>       transaction.commit()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 465, in commit
>       self._assert_active(prepared_ok=True)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 285, in _assert_active
>       raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg) sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "", line 48, in run
>       self.data_set.save_to_db()   File "", line 44, in save_to_db
>       session.commit()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 954, in commit
>       self.transaction.commit()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 467, in commit
>       self._prepare_impl()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 447, in _prepare_impl
>       self.session.flush()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2313, in flush
>       self._flush(objects)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2440, in _flush
>       transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 76, in **exit**
>       compat.reraise(type_, value, traceback)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 249, in reraise
>       raise value   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2440, in _flush
>       transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 483, in rollback
>       self._assert_active(prepared_ok=True, rollback_ok=True)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 285, in _assert_active
>       raise sa_exc.ResourceClosedError(closed_msg) sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "", line 53, in run
>       self.data_set = StockLive.find_by_ticker(self.ccy)   File "", line 52, in find_by_ticker
>       ticker_id = StockMaster.find_by_ticker(ticker).id   File "", line 23, in find_by_ticker
>       return session.query(StockMaster).filter(StockMaster.ticker==ticker).first() 
>   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py",
>   line 2895, in first
>       ret = list(self[0:1])   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line
>   2687, in **getitem**
>       return list(res)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line
>   2994, in **iter**
>       self.session._autoflush()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 1493, in _autoflush
>       self.flush()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2313, in flush
>       self._flush(objects)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2400, in _flush
>       subtransactions=True)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 865, in begin
>       nested=nested)   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 297, in _begin
>       self._assert_active()   File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 264, in _assert_active
>       "This session is in 'prepared' state; no further " sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This session is in 'prepared'
>   state; no further SQL can be emitted within this transaction.

Comment: i think you need to change the `pool` setting in create engine. by default it is 5 ( ur code is creaking for more then 5 threaad) so change it to ur needs.

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues with your code but an obvious one is that you share your `session` with multiple threads.

Instead of setting a global `session`, these should be created in each thread.

I am not able to run your code but you could try something like this:

Remove the global session variable completely. You do not need it. Then modify your methods and thread to include a local session:

```
@classmethod
def find_by_ticker(cls,ticker, session):
    return session.query(StockMaster).filter(StockMaster.ticker==ticker).first()
```

...

```
class Stream(Thread):
    def __init__(self,ticker):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ticker=ticker
        self.quote=1
        self.session = Session()
        self.data_set = StockLive.find_by_ticker(self.ticker, self.session)
        self.count=0
```

Or something like that. This will now make each thread have their own session and your code will start behaving better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that seems to have fixed one issue but raised another. The threads seem more stable, but the session.flush() process is now shown to be unstable. The error is "SAWarning: Usage of the 'Session.add()' operation is not currently supported within the execution stage of the flush process. Results may not be consistent.  Consider using alternative event listeners or connection-level operations instead." If I try session.flush() on its own, it still fails randomly.

Comment: Did you remove your global session variable completely (the line after `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`?  If it is still there, try removing it as you may still be using the global session somewhere in your code. For example where does the session come to your `StockLive` class methods?  You need to do exactly the same everywhere in your code.  Sorry I did not spot that initially.

Comment: If you remove the global session variable, your code editor will highlight all the changes you  need to make as there is no global session anymore. Every reference to the global session will now fail.